# How to get the path of the function call in Python?

Tags: python, django, introspection, traceback

I'm designing something similar to Admin.Autodiscover() of Django.

The first hurdle that I'm facing is getting the path of the file from which admin.autodiscover() is called, so that I can traverse the apps/libraries in that folder and figure out which models should be kept in admin.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zen of Python says: Explicit is better than implicit.

Why not call it like this: `your.autodiscover(__file__)`, or even `your.autodiscover(dirname(__file__))`. That way, someone who reads your code doesn't have to look for the magic in your `autodiscover` function, or look it up in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

Using `traceback`.

Here's one way I found to do that:

```
import traceback
def get_caller_filename():
   # last element ([-1]) is me, the one before ([-2]) is my caller. The first element in caller's data is the filename
   return traceback.extract_stack()[-2][0]
```